# Error after Entity Framework Upgrade to 6.1.3

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using .NET framework 4.5

I have upgraded Entity framework to 6.1.3 by command :-

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

In package Manager

But when I build my code after this, I get error:-

> Error 68  The type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

After researching few things on google I added below code in web.config :-

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" >
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
```

Then also I am facing same error.

How can I resolve this error to use entity framework 6.1.3 ?

Comment: Have you added System.Data.Entity from project references like this? http://take.ms/qLOkZ

Comment: It was already added

Comment: The mentioned dll file is not included in your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this command in Package Manage Console:

```
Update-Package –reinstall EntityFramework
```

However, first **ensure that you have selected the correct project from 'Default Project' dropdown** in package manage console.